# GraphQl function not adding to subdocument array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm trying to make an ebay scraper using SerpApi, GraphQl and React. It displays all my needed data , saves and displays correctly from localstorage, but the actual GraphQl function returns null, maybe you guys can see my error (sorry for the info dump, just want to give as much info as possible)

```
    // create state for holding returned eBay api data
    const [searchedItems, setSearcheditems] = useState([]);

// Data collection function with references to other calculation functions
const searchData = () => ({
      itemName: organic_results[0]?.title,
      itemId: id,
      quantity: organic_results.length,
      itemImages: organic_results[0]?.thumbnail || [],
      price: parseFloat(averagePrice()),
      purchasePrice: parseFloat(searchInput.userPaid),
      percent: parseFloat(percentage()),
      profit: parseFloat(profit()),
    })

      setSearcheditems(searchData);
```

The handlSaveItem function connected to button click

```
  const handleSaveItem = async () => {

    const itemToSave = {...searchedItems};

    // get token
    const token = Auth.loggedIn() ? Auth.getToken() : null;

    if (!token) {
      return false;
    }

    try {
      await saveItem({
        variables: {item: itemToSave },
        
      });

      // if item successfully saves to user's account, save item to state

      setsavedItems([...savedItems, itemToSave]);
      console.log('item successfully saved', setsavedItems())

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    };
  };
```

The request payload looks okay

```
{operationName: "saveItem",…}
operationName: "saveItem"
query: "mutation saveItem($item: itemInput!) {\n  saveItem(item: $item) {\n    _id\n    username\n    email\n    savedItems {\n      itemId\n      purchasePrice\n      price\n      itemName\n      percent\n      profit\n      quantity\n      itemImages\n      purchasePrice\n      quantity\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"
variables: {item: {itemName: "Hot Wheels Team Transport Nissan Skyline GT-R (BNR-34) Aero Lift JDM",…}}
item: {itemName: "Hot Wheels Team Transport Nissan Skyline GT-R (BNR-34) Aero Lift JDM",…}
itemId: "06dbdae7a5dcf13a1b2ffbf02fff2a08"
itemImages: "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/0OoAAOSwWyhgbWTB/s-l225.jpg"
itemName: "Hot Wheels Team Transport Nissan Skyline GT-R (BNR-34) Aero Lift JDM"
percent: 214.1
price: 94.22
profit: 64.22
purchasePrice: 30
quantity: 21
```

But the response returns null for everything and returns multiple objects of null values.

```
{data: {saveItem: {_id: "61f4db7aa9d6bd0508130d93", username: "test", email: "test@test.com",…}}}
data: {saveItem: {_id: "61f4db7aa9d6bd0508130d93", username: "test", email: "test@test.com",…}}
saveItem: {_id: "61f4db7aa9d6bd0508130d93", username: "test", email: "test@test.com",…}
email: "test@test.com"
savedItems: [{itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…},…]
0: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
1: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
2: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
3: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
4: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
5: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
6: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
7: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
8: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
9: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
10: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
11: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
12: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
13: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
14: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
15: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
16: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
17: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
18: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
19: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
20: {itemId: null, purchasePrice: null, price: null, itemName: null, percent: null, profit: null,…}
username: "test"
__typename: "User"
_id: "61f4db7aa9d6bd0508130d93"
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `saveItem` function? It's hard to guess because the front-end part seems to be fine.

Comment: Hi IIya, sorry for delay, been busy at work. I figured it out, turns out I was only referencing the outer object and needed to access the inner part by doing

Comment: itemToSave.item in setSavedItems function instead of just itemToSave

Comment: So have you solved the problem completely?

Comment: Yep, that solved the problem